# Trying to export EE to WordPress and I can't get all of the content to show

Tags: export, database-migrations

I have a EE site that I'm trying to export to a WordPress site using this guide https://kingdesignllc.com/blog/migrating-from-expression-engine-to-wordpress/. It's working ok, except I can't get all of the content to import into WordPress.

This brings in a couple of paragraphs - `<content:encoded><![CDATA[{body}]]></content:encoded>` - but the rest of the content can't be imported because it's within this tag:

```
<wp:meta_key>extended</wp:meta_key>
<wp:meta_value><![CDATA[{extended}]]></wp:meta_value>
<excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[{summary}]]></excerpt:encoded>
```

Anyone have an idea on how to combine the two so I can import all of the content? The entire template is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>

<link>{site_url}</link>
<description>My Site</description>
<pubDate>{current_time format="{DATE_RSS}"}</pubDate>
<generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=2.8.6</generator>
<language>en</language>
<wp:wxr_version>1.0</wp:wxr_version>
<wp:base_site_url>{homepage}</wp:base_site_url>
<wp:base_blog_url>{site_url}</wp:base_blog_url>
{exp:weblog:categories style="linear" weblog="default_site"}
<wp:category>
<wp:category_nicename>{category_url_title}</wp:category_nicename>
<wp:category_parent></wp:category_parent>
<wp:cat_name><![CDATA[{category_name}]]></wp:cat_name>
</wp:category>
{/exp:weblog:categories}
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="default_site" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="200" offset="0" rdf="off"}
<item>
<title>{exp:xml_encode}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
<link>localhost:8000/?p={entry_id}</link>
<pubDate>{entry_date format="{DATE_RSS}"}</pubDate>
<dc:creator><![CDATA[{author}]]></dc:creator>
{categories}

<category domain="category" nicename="{category_url_title}"><![CDATA[{category_name}]]></category>
{/categories}
<guid isPermaLink="false">localhost:8000/?p={entry_id}</guid>
<description></description>
<content:encoded><![CDATA[{body}]]></content:encoded>
<wp:meta_key>extended</wp:meta_key>
<wp:meta_value><![CDATA[{extended}]]></wp:meta_value>
<excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[{summary}]]></excerpt:encoded>
<wp:post_id>{entry_id}</wp:post_id>
<wp:post_date>{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date>
<wp:post_date_gmt>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date_gmt>
<wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
<wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
<wp:status>publish</wp:status>
<wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
<wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
<wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
<wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
<wp:postmeta>

</wp:postmeta>
{embed="comments.xml" the_entry_id="{entry_id}"}
</item>
{/exp:weblog:entries}
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Which version of EE are you exporting from?  Which version of WP are you trying to import to?  And (just curious) why are you (or the client) doing this at all... an update to a modern version of EE would be simpler (one-click for many systems) and leave you with a better end-point (for you and the client)...

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you need to adjust this line of code:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[{body}]]></content:encoded>
```

to use the correct combination of these tags which are holding the content:
`{summary}{extended}{body}`

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[{summary}{extended}{body}]]></content:encoded>
```